# Why isn't my water heater working after a leak and reset?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

This morning I found a shutoff valve leaking in the basement.  It was on piping running from the water heater out to the garage.  I turned it off, cleaned up the water, reset (button inside) the water heater (because it isn't heating), flipped the circuit breakers back on that had flipped off and zip - the water heater is still not working.  It is still damp all over the place.

The 50 gallon AO Smith electric water heater is  14 years old.  Does not seem to be leaking.

Should I try resetting it again?  Do I need to replace it?

Any help figuring out how to troubleshoot would be great (I don't mind trying, but I don't have the proper equipment, so please note what I would exactly need and I will pick it up at the hardware store)

Thanks a million

Comment: What did the pipe with the leaking valve lead to, out in the garage? If the breaker for the water heater had tripped, that's typically a bad sign, especially on a 14 year old unit. [Edit]ing in some pictures might be helpful.

Comment: With electric water heaters it is either the elements or the thermostat.  Repairing a 14 year old tank is iffy because they are old enough to start leaking any day now.  A multimeter should be the only tool needed to find the problem, a screwdriver and/or a couple of wrenches to fix/replace.

Comment: What does "zip" mean? Did the breaker trip again? Are you suggesting that leaking water caused a short, tripping the circuit breaker? If so, you'll want to let that dry out for a day or more before turning things back on. Fans help.

Comment: Had the water heater circuit breaker tripped off *on its own* or did you turn it off at the beginning of this?

Comment: @crip659 that depends if the anodes have been being replaced at appropriate intervals (which vary. by water condition. Ask the *USS The Sullivans* crew what happens when you don't change your anodes, or use saltwater anodes in a freshwater lake. This was not well covered because that same day, *Moskva* got the same fate.)

Comment: Maybe the "damp all over the place" is causing a short that's causing the breaker to trip again.